# Dynamically sending values to puppet manifest from jenkins

Tags: puppet, hiera

We use puppet manifest/hiera to create mysql docker instances in a specific server. Every time there is a request for new DB, we manually add a new entry in hiera which is picked by manifest and the docker instance is created. Now, we need to automate this process through jenkins. Is there a way I can dynamically send values to hiera or have some file sitting in the agent system, and puppet agent directly refers to this file to fill in the values for variables referred in manifest. I am thinking of the following options.
1. Add a new entry to the hiera from jenkins and commit the file (We maintain files in git), so this file is used by puppet agent. This involves a slight risk of failure due to multiple commits.
2. Have some file sitting in the agent system, puppet agent refers to this file to create new docker instances.
3. Any other way to achieve this?

I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: The *agent* does not ordinarily consult Hiera (or any manifest files).  The master does all that, builds a catalog of classes and resources to apply, with all their parameters, and sends that to the agent to apply.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking of the following options. 1. Add a new entry to the
>   hiera from jenkins and commit the file (We maintain files in git), so
>   this file is used by puppet agent. This involves a slight risk of
>   failure due to multiple commits.

Leaving aside the confusion about what component uses Hiera to access the data, yes, this is a viable option.  Probably also the easiest, since it constitutes a straightforward automation of your current process.

> 2. Have some file sitting in the
>      agent system, puppet agent refers to this file to create new docker
>      instances.

Seems possible to me, but where does the file come from, and how does it get the correct contents?  If the answer is "Puppet handles that" then you haven't really solved anything with this.  If the answer is anything else, however, then the combination constitutes extremely poor style, and it likely would bite you at some point.

> 3. Any other way to achieve this?

Lots.  But among those that seem most appealing, there is the possibility of adding an [Hiera back-end](https://puppet.com/docs/hiera/3.3/custom_backends.html) that obtains data from a database instead of a flat file.  Then Jenkins can store data in the database, and Puppet can read it from there, via Hiera, with whatever level of transaction isolation and referential integrity you like.  You don't have to *switch* to that, mind you, because the same Hiera configuration can draw data from multiple back ends.  There are existing Hiera backends for some DBMSs, or if you prefer, it wouldn't be that complicated to write your own.

Comment: option 2 was similar to the database option which you suggested in option 3. Instead of using DB, I was thinking of using a file located in the agent machine which can be updated from jenkins. But the DB option looks much sophisticated.

Comment: @UdayaMehendale, even more important than how the data get emplaced is *where they go*, which also strongly influences how and when they are retrieved.  From that perspective, I'm not inclined to agree that any approach that assigns primary storage of this data to the target machines is particularly similar to those that assign it elsewhere.